# Any information on a Turbo Delphi 2009 release?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

Individually, the Turbo Delphi releases and the new improvements added in Delphi 2009 are two of the best things that have happened to Delphi in a long time.  But currently you can only get one or the other.  Does anyone know if Embarcadero has any plans to release a Turbo Delphi 2009?

I'm a paying customer with my own copy of D2009, but I'm trying to set up an open-source project that's going to use Generics quite a bit, and it would really help with getting other people on board if the language was available as a free download.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's some info in [this podcast](http://www.delphi.org/2008/08/episode-2-nick-hodges/). What we know now: Yes, there will probably be one. But it probably won't be as feature-rich as the last Turbo was.

Comment: ...you know, I've heard that podcast. Must have forgotten that part. Thanks for the reminder! So does anyone have some more up-to-date info, since that was a few months ago?

Answer (score 3):

It was mentioned in the closing keynote at CodeRage.  No official dates, but they said they definitely want have a Turbo level offering.